# Send content block to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I use the following to get the content block in Content Builder.

```
%%=ContentBlockbyId("5642")=%%
```

So, can I make the id field ("5642") a column in my Data Extension table, so I can send different html blocks to people?

Comment: Please give it a try and update your question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself. I will post my answer here if anyone has similar issue in the future.

```
%%=ContentBlockbyId(TreatAsContent(
Lookup('test_non_sendable','html_id','creative_uuid'
,creative_uuid)))=%%
```

'test_non_sendable' is my data extension name. So, this function will look up the 'html_id' in this table and swap out the value based on the creative_uuid of the sendable data extension.

Comment: Would contentareabykey() not be easier? You could set the content box  external key as the value of creative_uuid and just retrieve the box eliminating the need for a DE lookup?